# How to write a Chef cookbook for multiple applications

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra

Imagine Jenkins is generating 3 different distributions - one on javascript running on NodeJS, another on python running on apache with python module and another on Java using Springboot. How do you write a Chef cookbook to install all of them on an on-premise infrastructure having bare minimal linux ubuntu distribution.  Scope of the problem involves capturing trigger from Jenkins and then kick starting Chef books to deploy these 3 apps. Based on configuration, either all 3 apps should be deployed on same infra or different deployment infrastructure.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Yours is incredible broad and I would say "well.. just do it, where's the problem"? You should clearly state what's actually the issue you're facing.

Comment: P.S: Those _playbooks_ are called _cookbooks_ in Chef terminology. I've updated your question.

Answer (score 0):

So a few things:

1. How you write the cookbooks is up to you entirely. I've got some examples up on http://github.com/poise/application_examples for Python, Ruby, and Node, but that's just my take on the subject. Whenever you ask "How do I do X with Chef?" the answer is always "How would you do X without Chef, and then automate that".
2. How to trigger deploys from Jenkins is a bit more fuzzy than that already-very-fuzzy answer. The simplest answer is to have Jenkins SSH in to each machine and run `chef-client`. However this might have security implications you don't like. You can look at more dedicated command-push systems like MCollective, SaltStack, or maybe Chef Push Jobs (though I would skip that last one). You can also just set up your nodes to converge automatically every 5 minutes so all Jenkins does it updates some stuff in the Chef Server to say which version to deploy and then waits 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar case to yours, using TeamCity instead of Jenkins. (But you can replicate similar behaviour)

In my case I use policy_files to manage my infrastructure, where I pass as attributes the build information so I can download artefacts in a recipe.
The main trick is having a build which is triggered by the services you mention (Python, Java... whatever), updating the attributes (build id, artefact name...) in the policy_file, when committing to GIT the result.

As a recap:

1. Build for your services is completed.
2. A build for your policy_files is triggered updating artefact download information.
3. Your usual build workflow.

In order to download the artefacts, you can use the remote_file chef resource, making a checksum verification to avoid downloading the same file on each chef run.